# How to modify background color (and other colors) in a entry with gi-gtk

Tags: haskell, colors, widget, gtk, background-color

I want to create an entry with gi-gtk and modify the backgroundcolor if the text provided in the entry is not in the expected format.

I tried to look in [gi-gtk entry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-4.0.8/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Entry.html) for a method such as 'setEntryColor' but I didn't find it.
What is the right function to do what I want ?

Comment: I am not that familiar with gtk, but perhaps this is done through a colormap? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:widgetSetColormap

Comment: Possibly through the `attributes` property. There is a [`attrBackgroundNew`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-pango-1.0.29/docs/GI-Pango-Functions.html#v:attrBackgroundNew) that looks relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to modify the class of my entry widget by using [widgetGetStyleContext](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.39/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Widget.html#v:widgetGetStyleContext), [styleContextAddClass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.39/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-StyleContext.html#v:styleContextAddClass) and [styleContextRemoveClass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.39/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-StyleContext.html#v:styleContextRemoveClass).

Then I can modify the appearance of the entry if all character are digits by adding or removing the "warning" or "error" class.

```
import           Data.Char
import qualified Data.GI.Gtk                                       as Gtk
import qualified Data.Text                                         as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    Gtk.init Nothing
    window <- Gtk.windowNew Gtk.WindowTypeToplevel
    Gtk.set window [Gtk.windowTitle Gtk.:= (T.pack $ "test")]

    vbox <- Gtk.vBoxNew False 5
    Gtk.containerAdd window vbox
    e1 <- Gtk.entryNew
    e2 <- Gtk.entryNew

    Gtk.boxPackStart vbox e1 True True 0
    Gtk.boxPackStart vbox e2 True True 0

    Gtk.onEntryActivate e1 $ do
        f <- Gtk.entryGetText e1
        case all isDigit (T.unpack f) of
            False -> do
                ctx <- Gtk.widgetGetStyleContext e1
                Gtk.styleContextAddClass ctx (T.pack "warning")
            True  -> do
                ctx <- Gtk.widgetGetStyleContext e1
                Gtk.styleContextRemoveClass ctx (T.pack "warning")

    Gtk.widgetShowAll window
    Gtk.onWidgetDestroy window Gtk.mainQuit
    Gtk.main
```

And that's it:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted already contains the answer. `Gtk.Entry` has css nodes, you must use css to change the color of the text or any other characteristic of `Gtk.Entry`. For this, you must use `Gtk.CssProvider`.

Edited: A little python exemple: first create a test.css file containing the css class with the changes you want to make, then:

```
self.cssProvider = Gtk.CssProvider()    
self.file = Gio.File.new_for_path('test.css')        
self.cssProvider.load_from_file(self.file)

self.entry.get_style_context().add_provider(self.cssProvider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
self.entry.add_css_class('red-text-image')
```

Comment: From what I've seen, CSS style is made to modify the style of every button, entry, combo in a program. I want to change the style of a single entry for a short time. Do I really must do that with CSS style sheets ? Can you provide a short example ?

Comment: There is no other way to do this in Gtk4 other than using css. As with any CSS, there are classes that apply to all elements, but you can create your own classes that apply to a single element.

I don't know how to do this in Heskel, but I'll edit my answer and include a Python example.